# How to generate javadoc in eclipse for a nested class?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

If this is my class structure

```
class A{
  class B{
    /* some methods of class B */
  }
  /*some methods of class A */
}
```

How should I provide the metadata for the class for generation of javadocs for class A in Eclipse? How should I tell the javadoc generator that B is a nested class?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think you need to tell the generator it's a nested class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen of docs you don't need to tell it, it will create a javadoc for the class A.B showing that B is a nested class.

http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/tooldocs/win32/javadoc.html ctr-F inner to find the mention

It says "Inner classes must be specified as outer.inner, not simply inner, for all forms." and I'm sure a good doc generator will do that